# Is "below ask" a valid combination of words?

Tags: grammaticality, parts-of-speech, above-below, zero-derivation

Is "below ask", correct with regards to information given below(suppose info exists below)?

Comment: I would say no, in general it is not valid.  (I guess we could come up with some contrived situation containing "below ask" that would be correct.)

Comment: It's impossible to answer your question because you haven't provided a complete sentence. We don't even know if that’s intended to me a Noun Phrase or a Verb Phrase. Just because “If there's water below ask for help” is fine doesn’t mean that “I didn’t agree to your below ask” is (it isn’t), let alone that “The first below ask asks below first” is (neither is that one, and it’s the NP part that’s wrong). Next, using *ask* as a noun via zero-derivation from the verb is a hip and trendy, and therefore distressingly annoying, bit of business jargon that rubs some people the wrong way.

Comment: It’s also impossible to say whether something “is correct” to all speakers and listeners; the best you can hope for is some measure of acceptability. Although the erstwhile preposition and sometime adverb *below* does see use as a kind of demonstrative determiner or postdeterminer via another instance of zero-derviation to convert its part of speech, especially by people who vaguely imagine that it makes them sound more formal when they avoid normal demonstratives like *this X” or normal NPs like *the following X*, careful writers might shun it with upturned noses wrinkled in displeasure.

Comment: In short, the twin instances of zero-derivation to convert two words that each are far more normally found in a Verb Phrase into ones finding themselves in a Noun Phrase may not produce the effect that you are hoping it will. It might be acceptable to some; it is probably unacceptable to others. Please read the duplicates for some perspective on this.